# What is known about doubly exponential series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, intuition

I've been exploring functions that have a general form:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{ a^{b^k} } \tag{1}$$

In particular, I'm now checking this equality, which seems to hold:

$$2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty{ \left( \frac{1}{2^{2^k}} - \frac{1}{2^{2^k\cdot3-1}} \right) } = 5/6$$

I'm also in the process of finding more identities/equations, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

So I'm wondering, **What is known about series of the form (1)?**  I'm interested in this and anything related to "doubly exponential" series.  I'd be extremely interested in any books or papers that anyone knows about.

Comment: The first term of the series shown is $3/4$, so the expression is at least $3/2$.  The second term is $9/32$, so even after excluding the first term the expression is at least $9/16 > 1/2$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas:  Oops, you're right.  It should be $\frac{5}{6}$.  I'll edit the question!

Comment: But $5/6$ is still less than my first lower bound of $3/2$.  Numerically the expression is about $2.196319819$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Sorry, I'm still not sure if it's correct, but I edited the result again.  It's my fault; I did a bunch of quick and dirty calculations, and I'm still working on checking and refining them.  That's one of the reasons why I'm so interested in finding existing results.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  And just fyi, the new sum is approximately equal to $1.069366217$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas:  Ok, I now have: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty{ \frac{1}{2^{2^k}} } = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^\infty{ \left( \frac{1}{2^{2^k}}\frac{1}{2^{2^{2^k}}-1} \right) }$.  Also,  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty{ \frac{2^{2^k}}{2^{2^{k+1}}-1} } = 1$.  They're not as great as I was hoping for, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Your equality cannot possibly be true, since the binary expansion of the left-hand side is aperiodic, thus the sum is irrational. Actually, transcendental, by a Liouville-type argument.

Comment: @AlexanderShamov:  Actually, binary expansions are exactly how I arrived at both equations.  I can write up the methods if you want, but we should note that the arguments I use aren't totally rigorous.  For the second equation, I started with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2^k}$ = 2.  For the first, I started with $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2^{2^k}}$, and worked to essentially cancel out all terms of this series.  I believe that if the methods work, we could find similar equalities for series of the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{a^{b^k}}$, with $a$ and $b$ naturals.  The equation in the question can't be corrected.

Comment: For $0<z<1$, and $b>1$, is there _any_ upper-bound?

Comment: I mean; one could always sum a first few (say $i$) terms and bound the rest to something like $2z^{a^i}$, but that's not very smart nor precise...

Answer (score 8):

The function
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{a^k}=z+z^a+z^{a^2}+z^{a^3}+\ldots,
$$
where $a$ is a positive integer, is analytic for $|z|<1$, equal to $0$ at $z=0$, and satisfies the functional equation
$$
f(z^a)=f(z)-z.
$$
For $a=2$, you have the additional fun property that
$$
f(z)+f(z^3)+f(z^5)+\ldots=\frac{z}{1-z}.
$$

Comment: Functions of this form can have what are called *natural barriers* which basically means that such functions cannot be analytically continued past their radius of convergence.

Comment: If it helps, I've also seen this condition referred to as a lacunary function.